# Mercurial server in Java without python and hg command

Tags: java, python, jakarta-ee, version-control, mercurial

Is there a mercurial server written purely in Java?

I found libraries ([Hg4J](http://hg4j.com/), [JavaHg](http://javahg.org/)) but these libraries use the Python `hg` command.
I'm searching for a library that provide functions like `org.eclipse.jgit` (example: `org.eclipse.jgit.http.server.GitServlet` and `org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceivePack`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Hg4J project](http://hg4j.com/) is a *pure* Java re-implementation of Mercurial — it does not require any other Mercurial installation. However, it's still a young project and the version 0.1.0 release only supports read-only operations.

You're correct that [JavaHg](http://javahg.org/) requires a Mercurial installation. I'm one of the authors and we wrote it like that since it's the officially recommended way to interact with a Mercurial repository from another language. We get all the benefits of new Mercurial versions for free and we have a full read/write API.

I agree that a pure Java version is interesting and I wish the Hg4J project good luck. But I also hope it isn't too difficult to install Mercurial to use JavaHg.

Comment: Yep, you're right. The hg4j project is a pure Java re-implementation, but many of features not implement yet.

Comment: hmm, if I want save all mercurial repository objects in DB(like jgit-mongodb), I must be write python code(gasp).